# Different responses from Graph API sharing OneDrive files

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, restsharp

I am using the graph api with RestSharp to give users permission to read OneDrive files:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/" + parentFolder + "/" + file + ":/invite");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"recipients\": [{ \"email\": \"" + email + "\" } ], \"requireSignIn\": true, \"sendInvitation\": false, \"roles\": [\"read\"] }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the success response should be (and normally is) in the form:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value":[
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "id":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY",
            "roles":[
                "read"
            ],
            "grantedTo":
            {
                "user":
                {
                    "id":"88902115-1090-4c29-9266-1b16b0a4cf64",
                    "displayName":"Test User"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But sometimes I get a response in the form:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value":[
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "roles":[
                "read"
            ],
            "invitation":
            {
                "signInRequired":true
            },
            "link":
            {
                "type":"view",
                "webUrl":"https://mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/userindomain/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrst"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Firstly is it OK to keep using `Invite`over and over for the same user or should I be checking whether they already have rights and only use `Invite` when they don't have the desired permission (needing more calls to the Graph API)?

Secondly, why am I getting this alternate response sometimes? Can I always ignore its WebUrl and use the DriveItem's WebUrl that I retrieved and stored when the file was created?

More Info.: This seems to be related to my domain. My users are logged in as aaa.bbb@mydomain.co.uk. This gives the supposedly correct response (without a webUrl).Looking at the OneDrive folder online, I can see that the permission has been granted, but the DriveItem's webUrl gives the user a permission error and won't open the file. If I use a breakpoint and change the email address to aaa.bbb@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com, I get the second response and the user can open the file using the webUrl in the response. The weird bit is that this is a new user who never had the address aaa.bbb@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com and I can't see this address anywhere in the user setup in Office Admin.